# How to scroll down in Rselenium until a specific date appear in facebook

Tags: facebook, rselenium

I a working with facebook and I want scroll one page until the first publication of 2020 appears. The problem is that I can't get the html text for each date at the same time that the code is scrolling down. This my code:

```
tryCatch({
  Sys.sleep(2)
  suppressMessages({
    vermas <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
    fecha_mirar <- remDr$findElement("css",".x4k7w5x.x1h91t0o.x1h9r5lt.x1jfb8zj.xv2umb2.x1beo9mf.xaigb6o.x12ejxvf.x3igimt.xarpa2k.xedcshv.x1lytzrv.x1t2pt76.x7ja8zs.x1qrby5j")
    fecha <- as.character(fecha_mirar$getElementText())
    while(fecha != "[2020]"){
      vermas$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
      vermas$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))
      Sys.sleep(5)
      fecha_mirar <-remDr$findElement("css",".x4k7w5x.x1h91t0o.x1h9r5lt.x1jfb8zj.xv2umb2.x1beo9mf.xaigb6o.x12ejxvf.x3igimt.xarpa2k.xedcshv.x1lytzrv.x1t2pt76.x7ja8zs.x1qrby5j")
      fecha <- as.character(fecha_mirar$getElementText())
    }
  })
}, 
error = function(e) {
  NA_character_
}
)
```

The idea of the code is scroll the facebook page until one publication is from 2020 and the code give me a NA to continue with other code.

The problem is that the only date that I get is from the first publication and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Thanks community!!!

PD: You can check the code in any facebook page.

Comment: Just a FYI. Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So don't be surprised if you get banned. Also the class names that you are looking for x4k7w5x and so on. They can change at any moment. So even if it works now. It will most likely break very very soon

Comment: Hi @WizKid thanks for the comment.. We already know that the class names change once a week or a month, but aniway for us is the best way to get the information. We check everiday the class names and there is no problem with this. You think that is any problem in the code?